# How to select the first visible row after applying a filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm filtering a table in Excel but I only want the first line that appears.

Comment: What does your filter statement look like now?

Comment: Come on, I just don't show becouse it is on my work, and I can't show this here, Is just a filter in a sheet, some lines was supressed, and I want to take the first line that appears

Comment: What's with the "Come on"? If you provide your vba for the filter, then answerers can give you specific advice of how to modify the vba to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with the [xlCellTypeVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) parameter on the filtered range. `.Rows(1).Cells` should be what you want.

```
Sub first_row()
    Dim rFirstFilteredRow As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            'do all the .autofilter stuff here
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    Set rFirstFilteredRow = _
                      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(1).Cells
                    '~~> rFirstFilteredRow is not a copy of the first visible row
                    'do something with rFirstFilteredRow
                End If
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

You will have to transcribe this to suit your own implementation of the [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

---

<sub>The native worksheet [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) was used as it only counts visible cells. This is an easy non-destructive way of determining whether there are any cells to reference after the filter has been applied.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
Worksheets("Raw").AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(Row, Column)
```

Comment: This worked for me .. inspired by the code above. 

frow_main = Worksheets(main_sheet_name).AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells().Row

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked beautifully for me.  First piece of code that did.  Thank you!

```
frow_main = Worksheets(main_sheet_name).AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells().Row
```

I was trying to find the first row after an autofilter, but other offset codes kept giving me row 1.

I needed row 27, but it wasn't guaranteed that it would be row 27 each time.

Your inspiration worked!

```
'Reset LastRow
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Remove the "Bear" invoice method
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=BEAR", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=#REF!"
FirstRow = Worksheets("testOriginalData").AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells().Row
Rows(FirstRow).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Range("A2").Select
```