# Sending an Email with VBA Based on Address from Specific Cell In a Filtered Table

Tags: excel, vba, filter

This may sound similar to other posts on StackFlow, but it is not. I could not find a thread targeting this issue.

Every month, I reach out to custodians concerning accounts I manage. I have a sheet that contains a table with all the accounts and their respective custodians in a single table. I filter by column E, and based on the custodian, I copy and paste the table with the information related to the respective custodian in the body of the email. This is a tedious process, so I attempted to create a macro that prepares and formats the email to my liking.

There is just one issue. If you take a look at the logic below the email address used is pulled from the email address located in column F. My initial thought was to filter the custodian I want, and when I press the button to trigger the macro, it would search the first cell in column F (F2) and inserts in the "To" field in the email. So, if I choose Bank of America, it works great because the email is in cell F2, and the Macro pulls that email correctly. The problem occurs when I filter for a different custodian. I thought the macro will look in that same area and pull the proper email address for the specific custodian. Because I filter the table, the custodian I am filtering is essentially in another cell, so it does not pull from what I filtered by. For example, let's say I filter for State Street in column E, despite the table looking like it is in the same place as Bank of America it is essentially in F22, so the macro does not pull the email for State Street. It instead pulls the email address for Bank of America in cell F2. Is there a way to direct the macro to look in the area rather than the specific cell reference to pull the email I want to send to thus limiting the issue if I filter the table?

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 
    Recip = [F2].Value & "; "  ' <-- !

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sht.Range("A2:F26")
        rng.Copy

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim vInspector As Object
    Set vInspector = OutMail.GetInspector
 
    Dim wEditor As Object
    Set wEditor = vInspector.WordEditor
 
    With OutMail
        .TO = Recip
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "STIF Vehicle Confirmation" & " - " & [E2].Value  ' <-- !
        .display
       
         wEditor.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "Hello All," & Chr(11) & Chr(11) & "I hope this email finds you all doing well." & Chr(11) & Chr(11) & _
         "Can you please confirm if the below STIF vehicle details are accurate for the accounts below? If the vehicle has changed, can you please confirm the new STIF vehicle name and CUSIP?" & vbCrLf
       
         wEditor.Paragraphs(2).Range.Paste
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You could probably use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to determine the first visible cell in the column after you filter.

Comment: `despite the table looking like it is in the same place as Bank of America` - does it though? There are row numbers on the left, they are what is important, not where on screen it happens to be.

Comment: Thank you. Where would you recommend I put it? Should I insert instead of sht.Range("A2:F26")?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select the first visible row after applying a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32864789/11683)

Comment: @GSerg that is my point. Based on the row numbers the macro will follow the hard code I embedded in the logic. Is there a way that I can have a more flexible code?

Comment: You are using hard coded cell value to get the email (`Recip = [F2].Value & "; "`). Try what @BigBen suggested. That will give you the relative row to get the email from

Comment: @GSerg looking at the link you provided, yes, it seems the solution may be one for this problem, but how would I incorporate that here?